How can I implement continous Z by using qiskit pulse?
I want to implement gate $e^{iXt+iYt+iZt}$ by using qiskit pulse. $e^{iXt+iYt}$ can be made when I change the Drive pulse phase. But I don't know how to implement additional iZt.
I think if there's way to change drive frequency or rotate frame, that kind of thing can be made.
Are there some qiskit pulse code apparents to available that method?
